# Passing parameters between HIS 2009 and AS/400 Cobol program

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange, cobol

We are using Microsoft.HostIntegration.TI.ClientContext.dll and Transaction Integrator Host Application libraries to connect HIS 2009 with AS/400 Cobol programs.

We are getting the following QSYSOPR log message “Message MCH0801 was detected in COBOL statement … Argument associated with external or internal parameter not passed.”

Testing COBOL program as follows.

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. TSTEBANK.
 DATA DIVISION.
 LINKAGE SECTION.
 01 NAME                         PIC X(30).
 01 ACCNUM                       PIC X(6).
 01 ACCBAL                       PIC S9(1)V9(2).

 PROCEDURE DIVISION USING NAME ACCNUM ACCBAL.
                 MOVE 555 TO ACCBAL.
                 MOVE “TEST” TO NAME.
```

The .net data types sent are string for PIC X and decimal for S9(1)V9(2)

Comment: Could you please show the calling side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should have used the DPC programming model when communicating with AS400 platform. Generating dlls from cobol files linkage section was easy with VS TI Projects, configuring the relevant DCOM component is also easy.